# My port scanning program hangs on connect_ex?

Tags: python, sockets, port-scanning

I am creating a port scanner for external IPs but it hangs on `socket.connect_ex` why? I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/port-scanner-in-python) a while ago and just modified it to this. I am mystified as to why it doesn't work...

Full code:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import random
import sys
# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('cls', shell=True)
for i in range(255):
    remoteServerIP  = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244))

    # Print a nice banner with information on which host we are about to scan
    print("-" * 60)
    print("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
    print("-" * 60)

    # Using the range function to specify ports (here it will scans all ports between 1 and 1024)

    # We also put in some error handling for catching errors
    with open("ipAdresses.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(remoteServerIP)
    try:
        for port in range(1,25567):  
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
            if result == 0 and port not in range(25, 67, 68) :
                with open("ipAdresses.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write("    {}\n".format(port))
            sock.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.error:
        print("Couldn't connect to server")
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this part is the problem:

```
range(25, 67, 68)
```

This returns

```
[27]
```

which (I suspect) is not desired behavior.
Instead, I suggest You use:

```
if result == 0 and port not in (25, 67, 68):
```

*EDITED*: Fixed code by adding timeout to socket

This will fix the code:

```
import socket
import subprocess
import random
import sys
# Clear the screen
subprocess.call('cls', shell=True)
for i in range(255):
    remoteServerIP  = "{}.{}.{}.{}".format(random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244), random.randint(2, 244))

    # Print a nice banner with information on which host we are about to scan
    print("-" * 60)
    print("Please wait, scanning remote host", remoteServerIP)
    print("-" * 60)

    # Using the range function to specify ports (here it will scans all ports between 1 and 1024)

    # We also put in some error handling for catching errors
    with open("ipAdresses.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(remoteServerIP)
    try:
        for port in range(1,25567):  
            sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sock.settimeout(1)
            result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIP, port))
            if result == 0 and port not in (25, 67, 68) :
                with open("ipAdresses.txt", "a") as f:
                    f.write("    {}\n".format(port))
            sock.close()


    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("You pressed Ctrl+C")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.error:
        print("Couldn't connect to server")
        sys.exit()
```

Note the `sock.settimeout(1)` line. This will switch the socket to non blocking mode (if this is not provided, socket will wait indefinitely).

Comment: Thanks. That may have been part of the problem but it hasn't fixed the hang. I commented out 'result = sock.connect_ex((remoteServerIp, port))' and it doesn't hang so it is to do with that line. I also replaced that line with a normal connect not 'connect_ex' and it triggered the error exception when it couldn't connect.

Comment: I have gone back to try the old original from the website and that hangs too. Have you tried it? I would be interested to know weather it works on your computer.